Converting Rendered Email Templates to PDFs - issue(s)
I'm hoping someone here will be able to help me as I have been trying different "solutions" for days now...to no avail.
I am new to Apex and do have some Java in my backgorund...not much though. At best, I'd qualify as maybe a Junior Dev.
What I am trying to accomplish:

Record-triggered Flow launched when a Case is closed.

This finds an appropriate Email Template

Once Template is found, an Apex Invocable Method is called.

This Method then takes the Case Information and Renders the Email Template that was found.

The idea is to then generate a PDF of that populated template and also send it as an attachment when the Email is sent.


Company Information:
The Company works in the Healthcare Industry and DRs are the ones closing these cases.
DRs can't be bothered with clicking a separate button to generate a PDF and add as an attachment.
Conga is currently used for this. However, Conga costs and, more importantly, their unreliability (major outage earlier this week) have made this custom solution a requirement.
What I have done:
So far, I am able to fulfill all of the steps - (mostly)!
I have logic that finds the appropriate Template.
My Invocable Apex actually populates an EmailTemplate and sends it out to the appropriate recipient and the received email looks just like I expect it to.
It also does attach a PDF. Therein lies the issue. After looking around for days, it seems like the Blob.toPDF() method leaves a lot to be desired? Or, what am I missing that can make this damn thing work???
Here's what I have for an Apex Method to build the Email Attachment (the Rendered Email Template passed as an instance of Messaging.SingleEmailMessage). The caseNumber is also passed through for naming the attached PDF file.
// Build the email attachment (the PDF) from the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage "mail" instance we created above
public static Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachmentBuilder(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailMessage, String caseNumber){
                  
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            
    attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
    
    attach.setInline(true);
    
    // This sets the filename of the attachment being sent. Used the caseNumber (which will always be unique)
    // and added "_closed.pdf" to the filename. Example filename => Case_00123_closed.pdf
    attach.setFileName('Case_' + caseNumber + '_closed.pdf');  // sets the filename to the Case_xxxxxx_closed.pdf
    
    // Get the HTML Body from the email message and assign to new String htmlBody
    String htmlBody = emailMessage.getHtmlBody();
                                                                  
    // Here we use the Blob Class to convert "HtmlBody" from above into a PDF. It appends this as the "body" to the
    // attachment we created in this method, named "attach"               
    attach.body = Blob.toPDF(htmlBody);  
  
    // Returns the attachment to the Invocable Method above that called it.
    return attach;
   
}  

I have found that if I use a basic - like nearly barebones VisualForce Email Template, the PDF is nearly...but, not exactly, perfect!
Here's the VF Code:
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="We have closed Case #: {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}"  recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Case">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <html>
        <body>
         <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
         <p>We have closed Case #: {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}.</p>
         <br></br>
     <p>Case Supplied Name: {!relatedTo.SuppliedName}</p>

     <p>Case Subject: {!relatedTo.Subject}</p>

     <p>Case Description: {!relatedTo.Description}</p>

     <br></br>
     <p><h1><b><i>THIS IS THE VISUALFORCE TEMPLATE</i></b></h1></p>
     <br></br>
     <p>
        <h2>Case Origin:</h2> 
        {!relatedTo.Origin}</p>
     <p>
        <h2>PA Opinion:</h2> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.Physician_Advisor_Opinion__c}" escape="false" />
         
     </p>
     <p>
        Case Reason: {!relatedTo.Reason}          
     </p>
     <p>
        Submitted By: {!relatedTo.SuppliedName}    
     </p>
     <p>
        Company: {!relatedTo.SuppliedCompany}              
     </p>    
         
     <br></br>
     <p>If you have any issues please feel free to reach out to me</p>
     <p>Sincerely,</p>
     
     <p>{!relatedTo.Owner.Name}</p>
     
     

    </body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Looks like this after running through the Apex Invocable and being sent out as an Email - perfect!:

However, the PDF rendering kind of starts to break a bit. In the PDF, the output has now indented the text for the Case Reason, Submitted By, and Company fields.
It should be noted that the field Physician_Advisor_Opinion__c is a Rich Text Field on the Case since I feel that might have something to do with the way Blob.toPDF() works?
Again, the rendered EmailTemplate displayed perfectly in the Email received. But, here is the PDF that was produced:

If I add an image or a table to the VForce, it doesn't work as a PDF...but the Email received is, again, perfect
Here is another (very simple) VForce Template code:
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="We have closed Case # {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Case">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <html>
        <body>
        <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
         <p>We have closed Case #: {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}.</p>
         <br></br>
         <p>Case Supplied Name: {!relatedTo.SuppliedName}</p>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"><img alt="1TestLogoLetterhead" src="https://xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com/file-asset-public/X1TestLogoLetterhead?oid=xxxxccccvvvvxxx" title="1TestLogoLetterhead" /></td>
                <td>Patient Name</td>
                <td>Case Number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>{!relatedTo.Patient_Name__c}</td>
                <td>{!relatedTo.CaseNumber}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    <br />
    &nbsp;</div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <em>{!relatedTo.SuppliedCompany} has reviewed your case with the following details</em>
</body>
</html>


</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Once again, the Email shows up well...but, the PDF...is not well.
Email screenshot:

The PDF generated doesn't even include the entire Table information and the image gets knocked around a bit...:

If I use a Lightning Template...well that's where the proverbial poop strikes the fan.
And, any time I include an image in the template...well...it just screws things up.
This post is already way too long...so, I'll spare you the details except to note that in Lightning Email Templates:

Emails show up perfectly - like the VF Templates

PDF generation adds numerous extra pages

PDF generation adds Styling to the top of the first page - I have tried String manipulation to try to remove this from the String being passed to the Blob but...it doesn't work. Here's an example of what that looks like:


Images and ALL text always gets centered on the PDF page even though "Left Justified" is always chosen in the Template itself. - one exception! If the Merge field in the Template is Rich Text, those fields get so far left placed in the PDF that they almost fall off of the left of the PDF page

Templates that are created using "Email Builder" where you need to drag a "Rich Text" section to build them are rendered worse as PDFs than those that are just straight Lightning Email Templates where the content of the template is created in the HTML Value section.


Sorry for the LONG first post. I'm really hoping someone can help me out here as my thinning hairline is becoming thinner by the minute!
If more information is required, please let me know! And, thank you in advance!

when dealing with PDFs, SFDC rendering engine is Flying Saucer that only supports CSS 2.1.  Related
